# Calling a method to change the ui after onCreateView()?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

Is it possible to call a method that will change the ui after the view is returned in OnCreateView or OnCreate? I want to show a Progress View and hide a listview until something has finished loading inside an async task from another activity. However whenever I open the fragment with this code:

```
boolean doneOnce = false;
    do {
        if(!doneOnce) {
            showProg(true);
            doneOnce = true;
        }
    }while (Values.courses == null);
```

through a navigation menu it freezes and then pops up, because this is being called before the OnCreateView is returning the inflated view. Any solutions?

Comment: "I want to show a Progress View and hide a listview until something has finished loading inside an async task from another activity" -- then have both in your layout and toggle their respective visibility (from `GONE` to `VISIBLE` or vice-versa). "However whenever I open the fragment with this code" -- a busy loop is never the right answer for GUI-related work in Android and is rarely the right answer anywhere in software engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Such a loop blocks the UI. How about using a Runnable, with your task followed by your required visibility changes? Something like:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //perform your task here
        something.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

and post this runnable through:

```
private android.os.Handler mHandler= new android.os.Handler();
mHandler.post(new MyRunnable());
```

EDIT: Perhaps you can still use a runnable, but from your main activity.

```
boolean doneOnce = false;

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(!doneOnce) {
            showProg(true);
            doneOnce = true;
        }
        if (Values.courses == null) {
            mHandler.postdelayed(this, 100);  //or mHandler.post(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, however the task is started in an asynctask in another activity, is there anyway to check if its done outside of that activity?  The task sets the static variable Values.courses to be something, and so I want it to show progress while(Values.courses==null). Is there a way to do that?